# audio stop working in fedora 36

Tags: linux, audio, fedora

I have recently installed fedora every thing seems normal but the sound stop working after some time when I'm watching video in Firefox or tor and goes back to work after rebooting or when I suspend and open the system again, but it stops again I was looked for a solution and tried :

`systemctl --no-pager --user status pipewire pipewire-pulse`
to see if pipewire is working, and it gives me this

```
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service.d
             └─00-uresourced.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-07-02 15:08:42 CET; 1h 4min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 1634 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 9043)
     Memory: 7.2M
        CPU: 21.020s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─ 1634 /usr/bin/pipewire

Jul 02 15:08:42 fedora systemd[1487]: Started pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service.

● pipewire-pulse.service - PipeWire PulseAudio
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-pulse.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-07-02 15:08:43 CET; 1h 4min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire-pulse.socket
   Main PID: 1767 (pipewire-pulse)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 9043)
     Memory: 21.1M
        CPU: 22.486s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire-pulse.service
             └─ 1767 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse

Jul 02 15:38:24 fedora pipewire-pulse[1767]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55cfb7a924c0 [Firefox]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:1303 error:25 (Input/output error)
Jul 02 15:38:29 fedora pipewire-pulse[1767]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55cfb7a924c0 [Firefox]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:1304 error:25 (Input/output error)
Jul 02 15:39:31 fedora pipewire-pulse[1767]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55cfb7a924c0 [Firefox]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:1305 error:25 (Input/output error)
Jul 02 15:49:56 fedora pipewire-pulse[1767]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55cfb7a924c0 [Firefox]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:1345 error:25 (Input/output error)
Jul 02 15:49:57 fedora pipewire-pulse[1767]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55cfb7a924c0 [Firefox]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:1347 error:25 (Input/output error)
Jul 02 15:49:59 fedora pipewire-pulse[1767]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55cfb7a924c0 [Firefox]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:1349 error:25 (Input/output error)
Jul 02 15:56:45 fedora pipewire-pulse[1767]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55cfb7a924c0 [Firefox]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:1920 error:25 (Input/output error)
Jul 02 16:02:10 fedora pipewire-pulse[1767]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55cfb7a924c0 [Firefox]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:2137 error:25 (Input/output error)
Jul 02 16:02:15 fedora pipewire-pulse[1767]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55cfb7a924c0 [Firefox]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:2152 error:25 (Input/output error)
Jul 02 16:06:51 fedora pipewire-pulse[1767]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55cfb7a924c0 [Firefox]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:2153 error:25 (Input/output error)
```

I don't know what to do, any idea would be appreciated